# data getting truncated while finding files in subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder called River, the folder has around 25000 sub folders. each sub folder has .tif and .pdf files. for example there is folder called 5443343 which have file SCN-13432.tif, I want a powershell code that can create a out file with name of folder and name of files in a subfolder the code I am using is

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object FullName | Out-file C:\river.txt
```

this code works perfactly in most of the cases, but I have noticed that data is getting truncated when path is big

for example

the original path is

```
C:\river\947692\DOC #3668937 - XXXXX Maintenance Invoice #1752182 Submission for Payment.pdf\SCN-322323.pdf
```

this code just extracts

```
C:\river\947692\DOC #3668937 - XXXXX Maintenance Invoice #1752182 Submission for Payment.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the width using the  -width param  e.g. -width 1000